# Bash arithmetic outputs result in decimal

Tags: bash

When doing calculations with Bash and giving it hexadecimal input, it does the calculation correctly, but it outputs results in decimal form. Is this normal? Obviously I want the results in hexadecimal since I'm giving them in hexadecimal. Is there a way to change this?

I know about `printf`, but calling `printf` every time I do a minor update to a variable with an increment or something like that, seems weird.

For example when doing

```
echo $((0xa+1))
```

The result is `11`, but I expect `b`.

Comment: bash doesn't know what kind of number you gave it, just that it's a number, and decimal is the default representation. If you want to see the number in hex, printf is the way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

`$((0xa+1))` is an arithmetic expansion that expands to the decimal representation of the evaluation of the `0xa+1` arithmetic expression.

That expression is not `0x` followed by `a+1`, that's `0xa` (hexadecimal integer constant), the `+` binary addition operator and `1` (decimal integer constant).

As far as I know the only Bourne-like shell that can have integer arithmetic expansion yield numbers in any base other than 10 is `zsh` and you have to specify explicitly what base you want the expansion in with this syntax:

```
$ echo $(( [#16] 0xa + 1 ))
16#B
$ echo $(( [##16] 0xa + 1 ))
B
$ set -o c_bases
$ echo $(( [#16] 0xa + 1 ))
0xB
```

And like in `ksh` you can assign a base to an integer variable with:

```
$ typeset -i16 var
$ (( var = 0xa + 1 ))
$ echo "$var"
16#B
$ set -o c_bases
$ echo "$var"
0xB
```

(ksh gives `16#b` there, the `c_bases` option (to give `0xBAD` instead of `16#BAD` for hexadecimal and `077` instead of `8#77` when the `octal_zeroes` option is also set) is `zsh`-specific).

Also, in `zsh`, if a variable is assigned inside an integer arithmetic expression (using the `=`, `--`, `++`, `*=`, `-=`, `+=`, etc. arithmetic operators), then it gets given the integer type and (unless it already had a base assigned to it) inherits the base of the rightmost integer constant that has an explicit base (like `10#12`, `0x12`, `0b11`).

For instance, `(( a = 0x10 + 0b1000 ))` is like `typeset -gi2 a=24`. Defines `a` as an integer variable with value 24, with `$a` expanding in binary (`2#11000`).

See `info zsh 'Arithmetic Evaluation'` for details.

`bash` did copy `typeset -i` from ksh, but not `typeset -i<base>`.

In `bash` to convert a number to a base other than 10, you can use its `printf` builtin for bases 8 and 16 as others have shown, or resort to `dc`/`bc`/`ksh`/`zsh` for other bases (the range of supported bases and how they are expressed varies between those).

For instance, to convert to base 30:

```
base30_dc() { echo "30o $1 p" | dc; }
base30_bc() { echo "obase=30; $1" | bc; }
base30_ksh93() { ksh93 -c 'printf "%..30d\n" "$@"' ksh "$@"; }
base30_zsh() { zsh -c 'echo $(([##30] $1))' zsh "$1"; }
```

Which give:

```
$ base30_dc 1234
 01 11 04
$ base30_bc 1234
 01 11 04
$ base30_ksh93 1234
1b4
$ base30_zsh 1234
1B4
```

Beware however than in `dc` negative number constants are expressed with `_` as the sign. While `-` is the binary subtraction operator (`dc` uses [reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)).

```
$ base30_dc _1234
- 01 11 04
$ base30_dc '0 1234 -'
- 01 11 04
```

As for the type of numbers that are recognised inside arithmetic expressions, that also varies between shells.

POSIX requires at least decimal, octal and hexadecimal constants to be recognised using the `123`, `0123` and `0x123` syntax respectively. Some shells like `mksh` or `zsh` don't recognise `0123` as octal by default as doing it gets in the way more often than it is useful (like when dealing with 0-padded numbers), only when some POSIX compatibility mode is enabled (`posix` option in `mksh`, `octalzeroes` option or `sh` emulation in `zsh`).

ksh, bash and zsh support the `12#123` notation to enter numbers in arbitrary bases (again, with the range varying between those).

zsh supports 0b111 as an alternative to `2#111` for binary numbers. And embedding `_` inside numbers to help legibility (like `1_000_000` or `0xdead_beef`)

ksh93, zsh and yash support floating point numbers (`0.123` (or `0,123` in ksh93 depending on the locale), `1e20`, `inf`, `nan`...). ksh93 also supports hexadecimal floating point notation like 0xA.Bp-3 (or 0xA,Bp-3 depending on locale).

Comment: great answer although at first I was confused by "As far as I know the only Bourne-like shell that can have integer arithmetic expansion yield numbers in any base other than 10 is zsh" -- but yes, bash isn't "storing" the value in a base.

I just wanted to add that in bash the printf built-in can help format the values back into hex or octal:
printf '%#x' -> 0xfd
printf '%#o' -> 0375

Comment: @DarkStar, yes I do mention that bash's `printf` supports outputting in base 8 and 16.

Answer (score 7):

Bash (or any other shell, really) is not a good tool for general programming. Bash doesn't even handle floating point arithmetic, let alone anything more complex. The shell is a *shell*, you can write simple little scripts in one, but you shouldn't think of it as a general purpose programming language: it isn't.

I'm afraid that if you insist on using bash for something like this, you will be forced to use more and more complex workarounds, starting with `printf`:

```
$ printf '%x\n' "$((0xa+1))"
b
```

The good news is that you can at least also do this:

```
$ printf '%x\n' 11
b
```

So you can easily convert from one to the other, which means you don't need to call `printf` every time:

```
var=0xa

((var++))
echo "Var (decimal): $var"
printf 'Var (hex): %x\n' "$var"
```

Running the above would print:

```
$ foo.sh
Var (decimal): 11
Var (hex): b
```

In other words, you can do your thing in hex and not care about how it is displayed until you need to print something out.

But no, you won't find a native way of doing this sort of thing in the shell because you are trying to use the shell for a purpose it was not designed for.

Comment: "In other words, you can do your thing in hex and not care about how it is displayed until you need to print something out." But in your example $var will contain "11" not "b", so if later in my script I want to add a number in hex let's say 0x1 to it, i must convert it again even otherwise 11 is interpreted as the hexadecimal number 11. Basically what I was asking is if there is a way to avoid such conversions every time i do a calculation

Comment: @confused_bash_user no, why? Try it: `var=0xa; var=$((var+1)); var=$((var+0xc)); printf 'Var (hex): %x\n' "$var"`. That will print `17`, which is `23` in hex. Isn't that what you want? The point is that `$var` contains a number. How you choose to represent that number is up to you, it doesn't affect the variable's value.

Comment: @confused_bash_user you can also try: `var=10; printf 'Decimal: %d, Octal: %o, Hexadecimal:%x\n' $var $var $var` which will print `10`, `12` and `a` respectively. The point is that you don't need to care about what's in the variable up until the moment you want to print it.