# arbitrary base conversion from base 10 using only builtins in bash

Tags: bash, shell-builtin, math

I'm trying to sort out a bash command to convert a number from base 10 to an arbitrary base, using a specified set of characters (for example, to base 26 using letters a-z, although that's not actually my use-case).

I *have* solved this problem before, but not in bash (which I have limited experience in), and not in quite some time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Easier if you use zsh: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/616227/70524

Comment: @muru zsh is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an examples with input and expected output. Showing your solution in a different language might also help. You could solve this with `bc` or (GNU) `dc`. Example conversion of number `1234567890` to base 26 assuming `a` = value 0, `b` = 1 etc. `echo 26 o 1234567890 p | dc | awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%c",$i+97) } END { printf("\n") }'`

Comment: This is one of those things that would be more sanely done in pretty much any other programming language; the shell languages are mostly about running commands and really aren't made for general-purpose number-crunching or data mangling. (though Bash does support the conversion in the other direction out of the box, using prefixes like `12#` for base 12 in front of the numbers. E.g. `echo $(( 12#100 )) $(( 12#bb ))` prints `144 143`. Not that it helps much.)

Comment: Related: [BASH base conversion from decimal to hex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191205)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had something similar lying around, so I polished it up a bit for you

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# usage: convert_base <number-to-convert> <output-base> <output-digit-string>
#
# example:
#   $ convert_base 3735928559 16 "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F"
#   DEADBEEF

decimal_number=$1
output_base=$2
read -ra output_digits <<< "$3"

# TODO various assertions

if ((decimal_number == 0)); then
    output=${output_digits[0]}
else
    while ((decimal_number > 0)); do
        digit=$(( decimal_number % output_base ))
        output="${output_digits[digit]}$output"
        decimal_number=$(( decimal_number / output_base ))
    done
fi

printf '%s\n' "$output"
```

Answer (score 2):

base 2-64 to decimal - just use [built-in BASH](https://phoxis.org/2012/07/12/builtin-bash-any-base-to-decimal-conversion/) $(( base#number ))

```
> echo $(( 36#B002RD3KCS ))
1117165531505356
> echo $(( 16#FF ))
255
```

revert conversion could be done with standard bc + helper function:

```
# base10 to base2..base52
# Usage: decimal_to_anybase <OtputBase> <DecimalNum>
function decimal_to_anybase()
{
   BASE52=($(echo {0..9} {A..Z} {a..z}));   # array of 'base_digits'
   base="$1";                               # output base 2..52
   arg="$2";                                # source decimal
   res=$(bc <<< "obase=$base; $arg")
   if [ "$base" -le 16 ]; then              # bases 2..16 returned as is 
       echo "$res"
   else                                     # bases 17..52 returned as array indexes
      for i in $res; do 
          echo -n ${BASE52[$(( 10#$i ))]}   # output BASE52[base_digit]
      done && echo
   fi 
}

> decimal_to_anybase 36 1117165531505356
B002RD3KCS
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe stating the obvious, but bash's `printf` builtin can do base 8 and 16:

```
$ printf '%o\n' 1234
2322
$ printf '%#o\n' 1234
02322
$ printf '%x\n' 1234
4d2
$ printf '%#x\n' 1234
0x4d2
$ printf '%X\n' 1234
4D2
$ printf '%#X\n' 1234
0X4D2
```

Even hexadecimal floats:

```
$ LC_ALL=C printf '%a\n' 1234.56
0x9.a51eb851eb851ecp+7
$ LC_ALL=C printf '%A\n' 1234.56
0X9.A51EB851EB851ECP+7
```

(here using `LC_ALL=C` to make sure the decimal radix character is `.`)

But it doesn't do other bases for which you'd need more advanced shells such as zsh or ksh93 or do it by hand.

To store the result in a variable:

```
printf -v oct %o 1234
```

is more efficient than:

```
oct=$(printf %o 1234)
```

Which in bash (contrary to ksh93 or the sh of some BSDs) means forking a process and send the result through a pipe.

For those who're not stuck with bash, some alternatives with some other shells can be found at:

- [BASH base conversion from decimal to hex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191205)
- [Bash arithmetic outputs result in decimal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/616215)